# React dnd useDrag and useDrop is not working properly?

Tags: react-dnd

I am building a chess board with only knight on it and we will be able to drag it according to chess rules.

I am using useDrag and useDrop hooks to move a knight across the board. But after dragging and dropping one time, it is not working after that. knight is not able to drag anymore.
here the code for reference.
https://github.com/sourabh053/lonely-knight